# Проблема с настройками .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Помогите пожалуйста решить проблему..
Я написал конфигурацию, которая выглядит (примерно) следующим образом

```
<pre>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(.*)/index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php(.*)$ /$1$2 [R=301,L]
</pre>
```

После этого в разделе ни один файл по ссылке(или по прямому переходу через адресную строку) не открывается, я пробовал удалять эти строки, сбрасывал кэш, но безрезультатно. мб это правило нужно каким то образом переопределить? и если да, то каким?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте следующие конфиги:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: спасибо, помоголо!